# How to set title to show only month name in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set the Full Calendar title to show only month name instead of "month name year name"?

**My code:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM'                // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
    },
    height: 'parent'
});
```

Using above code is not working and it's showing some js error on console.log

```
moment.min.js?ver=2.22.2:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.toUpperCase is not a function
```

That message is showing from moment.min.js file.

Is there anything I am wrong?

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define the view in which to show the month name. Check the code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    // Block should be like this
    views: {
      week: {
        titleFormat: 'MMMM',
      },
      month: {
        titleFormat: 'MMMM',
      }
    },
    height: 'parent'
});
```

For more information look at [Documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options).

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In v6 of `fullcalendar` you can do the following to only show the month name.

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('full-calendar')

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                titleFormat: {
                    year: undefined,
                    month: 'long',
                    day: undefined
                }
            }
        }
    })

    calendar.render()
```

In the above code using `undefined` for `year` and `day` hides them.

Or you can just remove the year and day from the object :)

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('full-calendar')

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                titleFormat: {
                    month: 'long',
                }
            }
        }
    })

    calendar.render()
```